# Как в chrome изменить title страницы при печати " save as pdf " средствами js?

Tags: javascript, html

при сохранении документа как pdf нужно заменить текущий title на value текстового блока.

```
не сработало- в консоли получаю новый title? а при печати он не меняется. 
function print_with_name(){
let temp = document.getElementById('inputText').innerText
document.title = temp;


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">


    <title>Консультация сосудистого хирурга</title>
</head>
<body>

        <div id="recom_print">
            <button id="print_btn" onclick="window.print();">Печать</button>
            <img id="image"src="image/2.png" alt="альтернативный текст">
            <div id="header">
                    <p class="clinica">Общество с ограниченной ответственностью "СМС "СтомаМедСервис"</p> 
                    <p class="clinica">188300, Ленинградская область, г.Гатчина, пр.25 октября, д.16</p>
                    <p class="clinica">тел. 8(813-71)926-60 www.smeds.ru</p><br>

            </div>
            <div id="head">
                    <div id="examinationDiv">
                    <h3>Консультация сосудистого хирурга</h3> <span id="examination"></span>
            </div>
            <div id="patientInfo">
                    <p>Ф.И.О. пациента:<span id="patientName"> Иванов И.И.</span>   Возраст: <span id="age"></span> Дата: <span id="date"></span></p>
            </div>

            </div>
            <div id="all" >
                <div id="inner">
                    <h3>Диагноз:</h3>
                    <span contenteditable id="diagnosis_text"></span>

                    <h3>Рекомендации:</h3>
                    <span contenteditable id="recom_text"></span>

                    <h4 id="doctor">Врач: Богданов А.О.</h4>

    </div>
</body>
<script src="BCA-arrays.js"></script>
<script src="Recom-print.js"></script>

</html>
<style>/*печать*/
@media print{
    @page{
        margin-left:1cm;
        margin-right:1.5cm;
        margin-top:0;
        margin-bottom:0.5cm;
    }
    @font-face {
        font-family: "Veranda"; 
        src: url("./fonts/Verdana.ttf"); /*format("truetype");*/ 
        font-style: normal; 
        font-weight: normal; 
} 
    html, body{

        font-family: "Veranda";
    }
    /*body{
        padding-top:15px;
    }*/
    #menu{
        display:none;
    }

    button, label {display: none;
    } 

    #recom_print{
        width:21cm;
        margin-left:0.5cm;
        margin-right:0.5cm;
        margin-top:50px;
        margin-bottom:0cm;
    }
    input{
        display:none;   
    }

}



html{
    margin:0;
} 
body{
    font-family: "montserrat"; 
    margin:0px;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "montserrat"; 
    src: url("./montserrat/Montserrat-regular.ttf"); /*format("truetype");*/ 
    font-style: normal; 
    font-weight: normal; 
} 
#recom_print{
    width:21cm;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:50px;
}
#menu{
    top:0px;
    }
#print_btn{
    position:sticky;
    margin-left:830px;
    top:90%;

}
#head{
    /*background: red;*/
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    /*position: static;*/
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom:0;
    }
#header{
    margin-top:20px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    font-size:12px;
    width:100%;
    /*background: yellow;*/
    text-align: center; 
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
#header>p{
    display: inline-block;
    margin:0;
}
h3{
    text-align: center;
    margin:15px;
}
h4{
    /*text-align: center;*/
    margin:5px;

}
/*#diagnosis_text, #recom_text{
    padding:50px;
}*/
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
#patientInfo >p{
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
#patientInfo> p>span{
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
                                    /*картинки*/
#image{
    height: 150px;
    width: 90px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:15px;
    /*margin-left:40px;*/
    }
#recom_text{
    font-style: italic;
    }
#diagnosis_text{
    font-weight: bold;
    }
#doctor{
    margin-left:70%;
    margin-top:20px;
}

#ps{ 
    margin-top:20px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    font-size:10px;
    width:100%;
    text-align: center; 
    margin-bottom:20px;
     }
</style>
```

Comment: Выложите пример Вашей разметки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если правильно понял Вашу задачу: (Заменить `title` страницы html)

```js
function print_with_name(){
    let temp = document.getElementById('inputText').value;
    document.title = temp;
    console.log(document.title);
}
```

```html
<div>
<input id="inputText" title="hello">
<button onclick="print_with_name()">Тык</button>
</div>
```

Если изменить `title` поля ввода:

```js
function print_with_name(){
    let temp = document.getElementById('inputText').value;
    document.getElementById('inputText').title = temp;
}
```

```html
<div>
<input id="inputText" title="hello">
<button onclick="print_with_name()">Тык</button>
</div>
```

По дополненным данным в вопросе:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">


    <title>Консультация сосудистого хирурга</title>
</head>
<body>


<div id="recom_print">
    <button id="print_btn" onclick="printt();">Печать</button>
    <img id="image"src="image/2.png" alt="альтернативный текст">
    <div id="header">
        <p class="clinica">Общество с ограниченной ответственностью "СМС "СтомаМедСервис"</p>
        <p class="clinica">188300, Ленинградская область, г.Гатчина, пр.25 октября, д.16</p>
        <p class="clinica">тел. 8(813-71)926-60 www.smeds.ru</p><br>

    </div>
    <div id="head">
        <div id="examinationDiv">
            <h3>Консультация сосудистого хирурга</h3> <span id="examination"></span>
        </div>
        <div id="patientInfo">
            <p>Ф.И.О. пациента:<span id="patientName"> Иванов И.И.</span>   Возраст: <span id="age"></span> Дата: <span id="date"></span></p>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div id="all" >
        <div id="inner">
            <h3>Диагноз:</h3>
            <span contenteditable id="diagnosis_text"></span>

            <h3>Рекомендации:</h3>
            <span contenteditable id="recom_text"></span>

            <h4 id="doctor">Врач: Богданов А.О.</h4>

        </div>
</body>
<script language="JavaScript">
    function printt(){
        let temp = document.getElementById('patientName').innerHTML;
        document.title = temp;
        window.print();
        console.log(document.title);
    }
</script>
</html>
<style>/*печать*/
    @media print{
        @page{
            margin-left:1cm;
            margin-right:1.5cm;
            margin-top:0;
            margin-bottom:0.5cm;
        }
        @font-face {
            font-family: "Veranda";
            src: url("./fonts/Verdana.ttf"); /*format("truetype");*/
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: normal;
        }
        html, body{

            font-family: "Veranda";
        }
        /*body{
            padding-top:15px;
        }*/
        #menu{
            display:none;
        }

        button, label {display: none;
        }

        #recom_print{
            width:21cm;
            margin-left:0.5cm;
            margin-right:0.5cm;
            margin-top:50px;
            margin-bottom:0cm;
        }
        input{
            display:none;
        }

    }



    html{
        margin:0;
    }
    body{
        font-family: "montserrat";
        margin:0px;
    }
    @font-face {
        font-family: "montserrat";
        src: url("./montserrat/Montserrat-regular.ttf"); /*format("truetype");*/
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
    }
    #recom_print{
        width:21cm;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top:10px;
        padding-bottom:50px;
    }
    #menu{
        top:0px;
    }
    #print_btn{
        position:sticky;
        margin-left:830px;
        top:90%;

    }
    #head{
        /*background: red;*/
        display:inline-block;
        padding: 0;
        /*position: static;*/
        width:100%;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom:0;
    }
    #header{
        margin-top:20px;
        display:inline-block;
        padding: 0;
        font-size:12px;
        width:100%;
        /*background: yellow;*/
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom:20px;
    }
    #header>p{
        display: inline-block;
        margin:0;
    }
    h3{
        text-align: center;
        margin:15px;
    }
    h4{
        /*text-align: center;*/
        margin:5px;

    }
    /*#diagnosis_text, #recom_text{
        padding:50px;
    }*/
    input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
    input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
    }
    #patientInfo >p{
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: normal;
    }
    #patientInfo> p>span{
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    /*картинки*/
    #image{
        height: 150px;
        width: 90px;
        position: absolute;
        margin-top:15px;
        /*margin-left:40px;*/
    }
    #recom_text{
        font-style: italic;
    }
    #diagnosis_text{
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    #doctor{
        margin-left:70%;
        margin-top:20px;
    }

    #ps{
        margin-top:20px;
        display:inline-block;
        padding: 0;
        font-size:10px;
        width:100%;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom:20px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: задача такая: я заполняю html форму,есть поле с ФИО. хочу, чтобы при печать->save as pdf имя файла было ФИО.pdf

Comment: @АнтонБогданов Добавил в ответ и в соответствии с Вашей разметкой. Постарайтесь в следующий раз сразу оформлять вопрос корректно. Первый ответ тоже верный в соответствии с вопросом до правки.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Все работает!